# Ubuntu 17.10 build-essential

Tags: apt

I would like to install my A6100 Wireless Dual Band USB. How would I do this on 17.10. I can do it on 16.10 just fine, but whenever i do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

I get

```
Unable to locate package build-essential.
```

I want to do this offline ofcourse, so without dependencies

Comment: you can get it here https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/build-essential there are also links to the depends

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure you have a wireless adapter, but with 17, I go through bloody hell with this

Comment: Is there a command that will just grab all the dependencies offline, because These go from dependency to more dependencies to more dependencies. It keeps going on

Comment: most of the packages needed to build a kernel module are on the install CD. If you installed without internet, the CD repo should be in your sources.list

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a CD.

Comment: `apt-offline` can help you make a complete install package http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-offline.8.html

Comment: I have 1 question. I just searched the CD files and would this be the download I need for the CD? It's called mini.iso https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: I'm not sure if the minimal will have all that you need. the regular install set should. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I ran the minimal iso through vmware, and without setting any wireless drivers up inside, it ran the installation. Now, is there anyway, since mine is dependent on my wifi adapter, and since Ubuntu quite possibly will not detect my usb, it wifi mandatory for the install?

Comment: no, wifi is nice to install updates, but you should be able to install from CD without internet, just remeber when you get wifi working, you will need to update as the CD repo will probably be lagging behind the online repos.

Comment: Get a CAT6 Ethernet cable and all your problems are gone.

Comment: Fabby I would, but i'm poor. xD

Comment: Ok everyone. I'm installing Ubuntu minimal install. I have a problem. Every mirror says bad archive mirror. I am using ethernet, and I am using another computer to send this question. Please help